# rotate command translates rect to another position processing

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, processing, rect

I have rotated rect by 35 in processing.Here is my code.

```
pushMatrix();
rotate(35);
stroke(74, 73, 74);
fill(156, 153, 153);
rect(cannon1PositionX,cannon1PositionY,25,60,50);
noStroke();
fill(173, 168, 173);
rect(cannon1PositionX + 3,cannon1PositionY + 4,20,50,50);
popMatrix();
```

But if i change rotation to 40 the rect is rotated and translated to another position. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that when you first use `rotate()` you are rotating in reference to the whole canvas so then when you use `canon1PositionX`, `cannon1PositionY` depending on the angle you are currently facing the canvas the position changes.

What you would need to do is the following:

```
pushMatrix();
// Go to the cannon position
translate(cannon1PositionX, cannon1PositionY);
// Rotate to the right angle
rotate(35);
// Draw the cannon at the current position and with the right angle
rect(0, 0, 25, 60, 50);
// Draw the second cannon next to the current one
rect(3, 4, 20, 50, 50);
popMatrix();
```